# go back to the previous page, reload the page without breaking navigation history

Tags: javascript, navigation, browser-history

I need to go back to the previous page and reload the page without breaking the navigation history.

I have this history:

```
Page1 -> Page2 -> Page3
```

Now from `Page3` I need to go back to `Page2`, reload it and remove `Page3` voice from the history.

The problems here are:

- If I use the `window.history.go(-1);` code, the `Page2` is not reloaded
- If I use the `window.location = document.referrer;` code, the `Page2` is reloaded but I would have a history like this:

  Page1 -> Page2 -> Page3 -> Page2

that is not what I want.
I thought about `history.replaceState`, but if I replace `Page3` with `Page2` I would have a history like this:

```
Page1 -> Page2 -> Page2
```

that is not what I want.